# python lxml tree, line[] creating multiple lines, desire single line output

Tags: python, xml, parsing, whitespace

I'm am creating an xml file with python using lxml.  I am parsing through a file by line, looking for a string, and if that string exists, I create a SubElement.  I am assigning the the SubElement a value which exists in the parsed file after the string I'm searching for.

Question: how do I get all the xml output onto one line in the output.xml file?  Using line[12:] appears to be the problem.  See below details.

Example file content per line:

```
[testclass] unique_value_horse
[testclass] unique_value_cat
[testclass] unique_value_bird
```

Python code:

When I hardcode a string such as below, the output xml is one continuous line for the xml tree.  Perfect!  See below.

```
with open(file) as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        if "[testclass]" in line:
            tagxyz = etree.SubElement(subroot, "tagxyz")
            tagxyz.text = "hardcodevalue"
```

When I try and assign the 13th character onward as the value, I get a new line in the output xml per `SubElement`.  This is causing errors for the receiver of the output xml file.  See below.

```
with open(file) as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        if "[testclass]" in line:
            tagxyz = etree.SubElement(subroot, "tagxyz")
            tagxyz.text = line[12:]
```

I thought making the assignment on the same line might help, but it does not seem to matter.    See below.

```
with open(file) as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        if "[testclass]" in line:
            etree.SubElement(subroot, "tagxyz").text = line[12:]
```

I have tried to employ `etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)`, and parse the output xml file AFTER the fact and recreate the file, but that doesn't seem to help.  I understand this should help, but either I'm using it wrong, or it won't actually solve my problem.  See below.

```
with open("output.xml", 'w') as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(project))

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse("output.xml", parser)

with open("output2.xml", 'w') as fl:
    fl.write(etree.tostring(tree))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lines include the line separator, `\n`. You can strip the line with [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

```
with open(file) as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        if "[testclass]" in line:
            etree.SubElement(subroot, "tagxyz").text = line.rstrip('\n')
```

In future, use the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) to debug such issues; you'll readily see the newline represented by its Python escape sequence:

```
>>> line = '[testclass] unique_value_horse\n'
>>> print(line)
[testclass] unique_value_horse

>>> print(repr(line))
'[testclass] unique_value_horse\n'
>>> print(repr(line.rstrip('\n')))
'[testclass] unique_value_horse'
```

Comment: Perfect!  So simple... all the difference.